# Suggested algorithm for diverging color mapping visualization

Tags: c++, visualization

I am attempting to write a piece of code that is suppose to map data to RGB values, and one of the types of visualizations I am attempting to use is a diverging color map.

I am not exactly sure what the best way is to go about applying the colors. The current algorithm I am using is:
        //F is the data point being checked

```
if(F <= .5){
    RGB[0] = F*510;
    RGB[1] = F*510;
    RGB[2] = F*254 + 128;
}else{
    RGB[0] = 255 - (F-.5)*254;
    RGB[1] = 255 - (F-.5)*510;
    RGB[2] = 255 - (F-.5)*510;  
}
```

Where the key points for the curve are:

```
      F=0: (0,0,128) 
      F=0.5: (255,255,255) 
      F=1: (128, 0, 0)
```

Are there any suggested algorithms out there for use instead of this, or is this hacked together piecewise function alright?
This is the image generated by this current algorithm.
[image: Color Curve: Divergent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a bar to test your function as it would be easier to see the transition 'speed' in linear data.

Here is a really good article for using the diverging colour maps: http://www.sandia.gov/~kmorel/documents/ColorMaps/

It describes the mathematics behind it. I know it seems an overkill to go through Lab and MSH colour spaces for such a simple task, but if you want good quality colour maps it's really worth it.

Other than that, I don't know of any 'manual' implementation of the function (i.e. not using already complex functions from matlab or R)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be more useful to use [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) as opposed to RGB, and show your data using the [Hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) component. This way all the values of your function will map to a nice rainbow color and will be evenly saturated.

In the provided links you should be able to derive the formula, how to convert the Hue value to RGB.